# IDE for HTML5 (html, css, js) development?

Tags: linux, html, text-editor, html-editor, editor

What editor (or '[IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)') do you recommend for HTML5 ([HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)) development?

My current preference would be a paid solution, as I find they are greater quality as opposed to free options.

My only requirement is that it run natively on Linux.

Comment: Not a dupe, but still liable to be closed as "too broad", unless the OP edits the question to say which features are important to him. Please read [ask] - the more information that you give us, the better that we can help you.

Answer (score 4):

I personally would recommend the use of Microsoft's [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). Using this tool allows you to [add additional extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery) (such as PowerShell syntax),

It meets your following requirement:

> **Which OS's are supported?**
>
> VS Code runs on macOS, Linux, and Windows. See Requirements for the
>   supported versions. You can find more platform specific details under
>   SETUP.

Your [languages are officially supported](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview) amd can be added through the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=vscode&category=Languages&sortBy=Downloads).

Lastly, there are a  few additional items I like about this tool:

- [Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) (How cool is that!);
- [User defined snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) and;
- [Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging).

Answer (score 4):

## WebStorm

JetBrains is a leading provider of developer tools for many languages and platforms.

[*WebStorm*](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) is their [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) for web development. That includes JavaScript, CSS, and HTML. This product offers [many features](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/).

Commercial product requires purchase of a subscription after an Initial trial period.

Runs on Linux, as well as macOS and Windows. See [system requirements](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/system-requirements.html).

[image]

Comment: I can't upvote this enough

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [Brackets](http://brackets.io/).

A very nice editor built for HTML5 programming. supporting other languages as well:

> **Multiple File Format**
>
> Support Brackets supports codes from multiple
> file types from C++, C, VBScript to Java, JavaScript, HTML, Python,
> Perl and Ruby. The complete list comprises more than 38 file types.
> This gives the user flexibility to work on various files of a project
> simultaneously.

Along with this, there are extensions available to add capabilities.

Comment: You forgot to mention that Brackets offers a "live preview" (its killer feature, imo). When you make a change in Brackets, it is immediately reflected in the browser, with no need for page reload.

Comment: @Mawg, yeah that's a pretty hand feature, too ;)

Answer (score 1):

**[Atom IDE](https://ide.atom.io/)** is also a package to consider after Facebook and GitHub joined forces in this project [few weeks ago](http://blog.atom.io/2017/09/12/announcing-atom-ide.html).

Based in **[Atom](https://atom.io/)** text editor, it is free, open-source, cross-platform and offers language support for all major programming languages:

> C/C++, C#, Clojure, CSS, CoffeeScript, GitHub Flavored Markdown, Go, Git, HTML, JavaScript, Java, JSON, Julia, Less, Make, Mustache, Objective-C, PHP, Perl, Property List (Apple), Python, Ruby on Rails, Ruby, Sass, Shell script, Scala, SQL, TOML, XML, YAML

Answer (score 0):

[Geany](https://www.geany.org/) is a text editor using the GTK+ toolkit with basic features of

> an integrated development environment. It was developed to provide a
>   small and fast IDE, which has only a few dependencies from other
>   packages.

- Cross platform;
- Light weight
- Supports multiple languages

If you use [KDE](https://www.kde.org/), the [Kwrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KWrite) editor is nice too, but it isn't cross platform like Geany.